# Send Sensor Data Over Wifi From One Arduino To Another Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want to send the data obtained by one arduino from the flex sensor to another arduino which take actions on the basis of the data recieved and I want to do this data transfer process over wifi. Can you help me how can I do this.
Do I want to configure a server on any one of these Arduinos or anything else ?

If I want to configure a server then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFiClient object wraps a TCP socket. A normal TCP socket is connected to IP address and port. WiFiServer starts a listening socket on a port. If server on listening socket is contacted by a remote client socket, it creates a local socket connected with the remote client socket on a free port and returns a WiFiClient object wrapping the socket. Everything you write or print to a WiFiClient is send to that one remote socket.

If one of your client boards creates a WiFiClient and connects it to IP address and port of the WiFiServer on your 'server' board, then you get there a WiFiClient from server.available() and this two WiFiClient objects are connected. What you write/print on one side you read only from the WiFiClient object on the other side.

client socket

```
if (client.connect(serverIP, PORT)) {
  client.print("request\n");
  String response = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(response);
  client.stop();
}
```

server side

```
WiFiClient client = server.available();
if (client && client.connected()) {
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.print("response\n");
  client.stop();
}
```

see the ChatServer example for a WiFiServer example